# How to ignore double quote in textfile

Tags: c#, console

This is what i get from a text file into mysql database [image]

i want it to be

```
Product_Name Product_Price QTY
Pepsi       30            64
Coke        35            24
Sandwich    60            14
```

This is the code.

```
try
            {
                var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\K\Desktop\New folder", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                            select new
                            {
                                File = file,
                                Line = line
                            };

                foreach (var f in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.File))
                    {
                        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(f.File).SkipWhile(x => !x.Contains("[Start]")))
                      {

                          string readLine;
                          do
                          {
                              readLine = sr.ReadLine();
                              string[] readLineSplit = readLine.Split('|');

                              if(readLineSplit.Length > 1)
                              {
                                  using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=pw;"))
                                  {
                                      con.Open();
                                      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products(Product_Name, Product_Price, QTY) VALUES (@Product_Name, @Product_Price, @QTY)", con);
                                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", readLineSplit[0].ToString());
                                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", readLineSplit[1].ToString());
                                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", readLineSplit[2]);
                                      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                  }
                              }


                          } while (!sr.EndOfStream);
                      }
```

Question 2: i have two text files in my path, any idea why only one text file inserts into my database?
[image]

Comment: Ask 1 question per question

Comment: In addition to the answers you got I'd recommend looking into [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128081(v=vs.110).aspx) because you can simply specify [HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: To answer question 2 we'll need to see what's going on until the `catch` - most likely you are suppressing an exception thrown while accessing the second file. You should be able to figure out what's wrong simply by stepping through using debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To question 1, remove the quotes, replace the unnecessary `ToString()` with `Trim('\"')`:

```
//readLineSplit[0].ToString()
readLineSplit[0].Trim('\"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your file content looks like, but can't you just replace the " sign with Replace?

```
readLineSplit[0].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
```